# Отключить возможность ввода букв

Tags: javascript, frontend

Есть спан с возможностью редактирования, использовать просто инпут не вариант потому что он сразу ломает всю верстку. Нужно чтобы при нажатии на любую букву она игнорировалась, именно игнорировалась, а не появлялась и сразу же исчезала, на данных момент она появляется и исчезает, как можно сделать полный ее игнор?

```
HTML
<div class="card-page__count">
    <button class="card-page__btn-minus">-</button>
    <span class="card-page__count__span">
       <span contenteditable="true" class="card-page__count__span__responce">1</span>
       шт
    </span>
    <button class="card-page__btn-plus">+</button>
</div>
```

```
JS
cardPageCount.addEventListener('keyup', (event) => {
   if (event.keyCode >= 65 && event.keyCode <= 90) {
         сardPageCount.textContent = '';
         return false; // не работает
   }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 cardPageCount.addEventListener('keypress', (event) => {
    if (isNaN(String.fromCharCode(event.which))) {
        event.preventDefault()
    } 
 });
```

Ограничить все кроме цифр от 0 до 9, в примере выше можно вводить и пробел, так что лучше использовать это:

```
cardPageCount.addEventListener('keypress', (event) => {
    if (event.which < 48 || event.which > 57) event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Спасибо, все работает

Comment: немного поправил ответ